# How to get the dimension of an array without using the built in function Rank in c#?

Tags: c#

I am really curious to know, the method to get the dimension of the array below, without using the built in function Rank in c#.

```
 string [,] random_array= new string[2, 2];
```

Comment: Well, it's more that it's part of the `Array` type than being part of C# itself. But why would you not want to use the existing property? The point of the property is that that *is* the simplest way of getting the rank.

Comment: @JonSkeet The pleasure of reinventing the wheel :-D

Comment: @Oscar Then wouldn't you want to create your own array type instead?

Comment: Because i was wondering that we do have .Length function for an array which returns the length of an array, but we could re-implement it without the build-in function, that lead me to this question.

Comment: Yes, you *could* reimplement it, but it would be foolish to do so. Some things *can* be reimplemented with other members, others cannot. There's really no point in trying to split the world into those two categories though. Can you see any *useful* purpose this would serve?

Comment: @juharr No, I don't have time neither necessity of doing that

Comment: That kind of question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are we allowed to cheat (and use really HORRIBLE code)?

```
public static int Rank(Array a)
{
    int rank = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            a.GetLength(rank++);
        }

        catch
        {
            return rank - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Utterly pointless, of course.

Comment: Maybe you can do `return a.GetType().ToString().Count(x => x == ',') + 1`. The rank is the number of commas, plus one.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen and that's the way we do it)))

Comment: Or if the `a` is strongly typed at compile-time, have a bunch of overloads `static int Rank<TElemnt>(TElemnt[] a) => 1;
    static int Rank<TElemnt>(TElemnt[,] a) => 2;
    static int Rank<TElemnt>(TElemnt[,,] a) => 3;
    static int Rank<TElemnt>(TElemnt[,,,] a) => 4;
    static int Rank<TElemnt>(TElemnt[,,,,] a) => 5;` and so on, then it even works if `a` is `null`!

Comment: This answer can in theory underestimate the rank if an obscure exception is caught for some unexpected reason. On the other hand, the comma-counting approach of my first comment here is too naïve in some cases, such as the type `Tuple<int, int>[,,,]` where there is an extra comma between the two generic arguments of the array element type `Tuple<,>` (the two-tuple). The problem also shows with arrays of arrays.